# Salesforce Optimizer: Inactive Workflow Rules

Tags: administration, performance

In our system, we migrated all the WFs and PBs to Flows. In the Salesforce Optimizer tool, it recommends us to delete all the inactive workflow rules. I guess my question is, how can inactive workflow rules impact anything in the system?

---

**Recommendation**

**Estimated Effort: < 30 minutes**

**Delete workflow rules that you don’t need, and use your sandbox to test changes before you deploy them to users.**

**We only analyzed Account, Opportunities, Cases, Lead, Campaign, Contact and custom objects. Objects from managed packages aren’t analyzed.**

Comment: I doubt they have any specific performance impact, but are unnecessary "cruft" and will still be listed in the Setup UI.

Comment: +1 for actually succeeding at converting WFR and PB to Flow; something we should all aspire to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just tested this, and amazingly, inactive workflow rules still take up some execution time.

With a workflow enabled:

```
09:42:38.0 (536879862)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
09:42:38.0 (536946558)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Account: Test xxxxx]|Test|xxxxx|ON_CREATE_ONLY|0
09:42:38.0 (537188890)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]TRUE|Values:
09:42:38.0 (537204762)|WF_CRITERIA_END|true
09:42:38.0 (537221245)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
09:42:38.0 (537234941)|WF_ACTION| None
09:42:38.0 (537241705)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
09:42:38.0 (537334682)|WF_TIME_TRIGGERS_BEGIN
09:42:38.0 (553930681)|WF_TIME_TRIGGER|[Account: Test xxxxx]|0 after xxxxx|Test xxxxx|09:43:38.0
09:42:38.0 (565875078)|WF_ACTIONS_END| None
```

And when disabled:

```
09:43:14.0 (577308517)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
09:43:14.0 (577371694)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Account: Test xxxxx]|Test|xxxxx|ON_CREATE_ONLY|0
09:43:14.0 (577390798)|WF_RULE_NOT_EVALUATED
09:43:14.0 (577561153)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
09:43:14.0 (577575908)|WF_ACTION| None
09:43:14.0 (577579552)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
09:43:14.0 (577635239)|WF_TIME_TRIGGERS_BEGIN
09:43:14.0 (582702770)|WF_ACTIONS_END| None
```

As you can see, inactive rules still take non-zero execution time. While this is admittedly a very small amount of time, if you have a ton of inactive rules and large transactions, this could start to add up.

Presumably, if salesforce.com is recommending that you delete inactive rules you no longer need, there have probably been orgs or scenarios where inactive rules were actually a problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying!!